# Sharing a static dll between WCF client apps

Tags: c#, wcf, dll, static, service

We building a static dll which is consuming a WCF services (has a service reference to a WCF service).

The static dll has local static variables which critical for the process.

The dll will be consumed by more then one type of GUI.

1. a WPF user control.
2. stand alone WPF application

Each one will have dozen of clients.

The question: is it possible to use one dll for all the clients by putting the dll to shared folder? Or can you suggest other method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Correct me if I am wrong but I assume you not only need need to share the same DLL, but the same state/values across multiple clients.*

If DLL is loaded by several clients each in its own process, then they will not be sharing the static information.

Static state/variables are shared within the same **AppDomain** only. So if you are trying all these various clients to be able to access the same shared state, loading the DLL from a shared  location will not help.

One solution to using shared information across multiple applications is having a services (could be WCF) providing shared state.

Comment: Thanks, it's a thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could always [register the assembly in the GAC](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/PrintSearchContent.asp?LINKID=713).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "static DLL". Linguistically speaking this is an oxymoron (DLL means "dynamic-link library"). If you are referring to something like static linkage, such a thing is not directly supported by .NET (AFAIK).

Comment: public static class DLLClassName()
{
...
}

Comment: You mean you are using static classes. That doesn't change what kind of assembly you get, though.